# kind mis-match when defining an instance

Tags: haskell, types, functional-programming, ghc

First program i'm writing while reading various Haskell tutorials gives me a "Kind mis-match" error

```
import qualified Data.Vector as V

class SupervisedLearner l where
    learn :: l (Input n) -> Output n

data Input n = Supervised (V.Vector n ,V.Vector n) | Unsupervised (V.Vector n)
data Output n =  Regression n | KClass (V.Vector n) | Bernoulli (n, n)
newtype Perceptron  = Perceptron (V.Vector Float)

instance SupervisedLearner Perceptron  where
    learn = undefined
```

What's confusing me is when i try to follow the type signature of the error,

```
Kind mis-match
The first argument of `SupervisedLearner' should have kind `*
                                                            -> *',
but `Perceptron' has kind `*'
In the instance declaration for `SupervisedLearner Perceptron'
```

I just can't seem to understand where I should look to even begin to correct it.
So my question is two fold, where is the error, and a generally sense, am I using the Haskell typeclass system correctly?

Comment: Can you verify the error message?  When I try to compile it, I get a different kind error.  It says that SupervisedLearner should have kind `* -> *`.

Comment: fixed the error message to what it truly shows for me, questions still stand the same though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to your class definition, you need to define a method `learn` of type `l (Input n) -> Output n` to make `l` an instance of `SupervisedLearner`. So to make Perceptron an instance of `SupervisedLearner`, `learn` would have to have the type `Perceptron (Input n) -> Output n`.

But the `Perceptron` type doesn't take any type arguments, so `Perceptron (Input n)` is not a valid type. That's what the error message is complaining about (kind `*` means that a type doesn't take any type arguments and kind `* -> *` means that a type takes one type argument).

Comment: Thanks, took a few reads, but that makes sense. What I thought happened was the instance that I defined would have replaced the type variable in the class definition so `learn :: l (Input n) -> Output n` would then become ` learn:: Perceptron (V.Vector Float) (Input n) -> Output n`